# Unable to deploy app to Windows 10 IOT

Tags: win-universal-app, iot

I'm using `Windows 7` with `VS 2015 Community` to develop a `UWP` app and trying to deploy it to a `Raspberry Pi 3` running `Windows 10 IOT`. Authentication mode is set to no authentication and I have started the remote debugger manually over ssh.

When I try to deploy the app to the pi using VS, I get this:

> Error : DEP2500 : Registration succeeded, but package registration
>   information cannot be found. The layout folder is
>   "C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\APPNAME"

I previously had this error and was able to change the package name and it deployed successfully, but that is no longer working. I can open up the IOT web server on the pi and start the app from there and it runs correctly, but then I am unable to debug.

I have also tried using different authentication modes but they each have their own problems.

Windows authentication yields:

> WindowsAppDeployer::Unable to connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio
>   Remote Debugger named '192.168.1.42'.  Connection request was rejected
>   by the remote debugger. Ensure that the remote debugger is running in
>   'Windows Authentication' mode.

Universal authentication yields:

> Error : DEP6701 : Bootstrapping failed with unexpected error: 'Error :
>   DEP6960 : Source file does not exist: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
>   Files\Microsoft Shared\Phone
>   Tools\14.0\Debugger\target\armv4i\msvsmon.exe'.   App1

I'm new to UWP and am not familiar with Windows 10 so any help would be appreciated

Comment: I'm having the same problem trying to deploy a basic UWP app from Windows 10 VS2015 getting the error about `msvsmon.exe`

Answer (score 0):

In the application manifest, try to change one letter in the Package name property of the Packaging tab.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar problem after the update 3 from VS15:

Error : DEP6701 : Bootstrapping failed with unexpected error: 'Error : DEP6960 : Source file does not exist: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Phone Tools\14.0\Debugger\target\armv4i\1031\DiagnosticsHubMsg.dll".".   FirstTest

I solved this problem!  You need to change all directory-names with 1033 to 1031.

There are three directories:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Phone Tools\14.0\Debugger\target\armv4i\

C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Phone Tools\14.0\DiagnosticsHub\target\armv4i

C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Phone Tools\14.0\DiagnosticsHub\target\armv4i\Collector

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when switching from `Debug` to `Release` when deploying to the Hololens. I fixed it by uninstalling the app from the Hololens then re-deploying.